# Blankpage in the react aplication in a subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, apache, url

I'm currently facing an issue with my React application, which is hosted in a subdirectory `/system`, alongside my WordPress website. When I access the application through the primary address, `https://example.digital/system`, it works as expected. However, after the initial access, the URL becomes something like `https://example.digital/system/access/enter`. The problem arises when I hit the "F5" or "Ctrl + F5" keys to refresh the page, as it only shows a blank page without any content.

My application is running on an Apache HTTP server (httpd), and here's my server configuration:

```
apache
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName system.digital
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile example

    ErrorLog "logs/system.digital-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/system.digital-access_log" common

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /sistema /var/www/html/system
    <Directory /var/www/html/system>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /system
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* /system/index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my package.json, I've set the homepage to "https://system.digital/system", and in my index.tsx, I've configured the  with basename="/system".

In the public directory, my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
apache

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /system
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteRule .* /system/index.html [L]
  RewriteRule .* index.html
</IfModule>
```

I've tried various solutions, but none have resolved the issue. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me with this. Thank you in advance for your help. ❤️

I've tried too many things, changing all the configurations of the .htaccess and the configuration of the httpd.

Comment: Don't double-up on mod_rewrite configuration

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` is in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file